# itertaing over inputjsonarray

Tags: java, json, rest

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.json.JSONArray;


    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    /**
     *
     * @author rajshree.some
     */
    public class sample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    //        JSONArray arrayinputip = new JSONArray();
    //        arrayinputip.put("10.253.140.116");
    //        arrayinputip.put("10.253.140.111");
    //        arrayinputip.put("10.253.140.118");
    //        arrayinputip.put("10.253.140.110");
    //        JSONArray arrayinputusername = new JSONArray();
    //        arrayinputusername.put("10.253.140.116");
    //        arrayinputusername.put("10.253.140.111");
    //        arrayinputusername.put("10.253.140.118");
    //        arrayinputusername.put("10.253.140.110");
    //        JSONArray arrayinput = new JSONArray();
    //        arrayinput.put("10.253.140.116");
    //        arrayinput.put("10.253.140.111");
    //        arrayinput.put("10.253.140.118");
    //        arrayinput.put("10.253.140.110");

            JSONObject inputJsonObj1 = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject inputJsonObj2 = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject inputJsonObj3 = new JSONObject();

            JSONArray array= new JSONArray();
            try {
                inputJsonObj1.put("ipaddress","10.253.140.116");
                inputJsonObj1.put("username","bwadmin");
                inputJsonObj1.put("password","c0mcast!");

                inputJsonObj2.put("ipaddress","10.253.140.117");
                inputJsonObj2.put("username","bwadmin");
                inputJsonObj2.put("password","bwadmin!");


                array.put(inputJsonObj1);
                array.put(inputJsonObj2);
               // inputJsonObj3.put("server",array);
                System.out.println(array);

                Client client = Client.create();
                WebResource webResource = client.
                        resource("http://10.85.249.29:8080/checkRest/CheckxARC/getVersion");
                ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").
                        post(ClientResponse.class, array.toString());
                String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

                System.out.println(" op--->" + output);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " ");
            }

        }
    }
    //This is my clinet code for calling a resftful webservice.

//This is my api
@Path("/getVersion")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getVersion(String getVersionJson) {
        String version = "", patches = "", connectionStatus = "", output1 = "", output2 = "";
        String output3[] = new String[100];
        try {
            JSONArray inputarray = new JSONArray();
            inputarray.put(getVersionJson);
            JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject(getVersionJson);
            String ip = inputJson.getString("ipaddress").trim();

            for(int i=0;i<inputarray.length();i++){
                output3[i]=inputarray.getString(inputarray[i]);
            }
            String userName = inputJson.getString("username").trim();
            String passWord = inputJson.getString("password").trim();
            connectionStatus = getSSHConnection(ip, userName, passWord);

            if (connectionStatus.equals("Connected")) {

                //Version Check
                expect.send("bwshowver" + "\n");
                if (expect.expect("$") > -1) {
                    String contt = "";
                    contt = (expect.before);
                    if (contt != null && contt != "") {

                        contt = contt.replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
                        contt = contt.replaceAll(" +", " ");

                        String splitter[] = contt.split("\n");

                        for (int i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
//                         
                            if (splitter[i].contains("Patches")) {
                                patches = splitter[i];
                            }
                            //version
                            if (splitter[i].contains("version")) {
                                version = splitter[i];
                            }
//                            output1=version.toString();
//                            output2=patches.toString();
//                             output3=output1+output2;
//                                     
                            output1 = contt;
                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    output1 = "Error in version check";
                    System.out.println("Error in version check");
                }

            } else {
                output1 = connectionStatus;
                System.out.println(connectionStatus);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            output1 = "Error";
            //     logger.error("Exception in getVersion Function-ServService Class: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            stopSSH();
        }

        return output1;
    }
```

//In my client calling a restful webservice I am sending ipaddress,password,username of two service and I am binding them in an array and calling them.
 Now in the calling method I need to access each ipaddress,username and password .But i am not being able to access the ipaddress,username and password.Can u please show me some ways to solve it.

Comment: What have you tried? In what way was it insufficient or didn’t work?

Comment: in my client side code I am sending the array which comprises of two json objects which hold ipaddress,username and password.Now I want to access each ipaddress,username and password in my called function(which is get-version).Can u please suggest me how I will be able to proceed it.